# Start activity in landscape mode and it can rotate to portrait also

Tags: android, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait, onconfigurationchanged

I am developing an app having one activity have two different views for `Landscape` and `Portrait` mode. Everything fine on handling orientation but the problem is that I want to show `Landscape` mode first and then user can change orientation to portrait later whether previous activity is in `Portrait` mode.

when I am forcefully defining orientation to `landscape` in manifest or by calling in **onCreate** `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` 
    then method **onConfigurationChanged**

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

not being called.

I have also defined

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

in Manifest .

Any help will appreciable.

Comment: "show landscape mode first and then user can change orientation to portrait later." So, user is in portrait mode, activity starts landscape. And if they want portrait, they need to rotate device twice? What a nonsence

Comment: manually setting orientation to landscape locks orientation changing, so onConfigurationChanged method not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative option using a OrientationEventListener in your Activity code:

```
private OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

            // ....

        }
    };

    if (orientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        orientationEventListener.enable();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    orientationEventListener.disable();
}
```

Comment: tried but the values is not correct for orientation.